# How to deal with decimal operation errors in dart?

Tags: dart, floating-point, decimal

I am trying to fix the decimal error generated in my program.

For example I have the code:-

```
void main() {
  double a = 300;
  double b = 150;
  double c = 33.33;
  double d = 100;

//sum is exact 583.33

  double average = (a+b+c+d)/4;

  print(average);

  print(average*4);

//I want to get back the original sum
}
```

This gives the outputs:-

```
145.83249999999998
583.3299999999999
```

As shown above, I wanted to get back the original sum that is 583.33, but when I multiplied the average by 4, I got 583.3299999999999, which is a slight error but this error is causing troubles with my program.

How should I fix this?

Comment: Where did you get the information that these are errors? You already read the specification and found there information that this should not be? And what should the result really be, in your opinion, in accordance with the specification?

Comment: Forgot to add, this is not decimal, this is floating point. Dart does not support the decimal data type.  https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/681

Comment: @mezoni I am talking about mathematical errors you can read more about them here https://www.britannica.com/science/error-mathematics, and what the result should be I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: IEEE 754 is not intended for high precision mathematical calculations. This standard supports limited precision calculations. It is unlikely that Dart can be recommended for such mathematical calculations. As well as other similar programming languages.

Comment: As noted in the GitHub issue, there is a third-party Decimal package.